# Make UITableView scrollable by index

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, indexing

I am trying to create a `UITableView` index for faster scrolling of a large `UITableView`, I have the index showing up on the right but when I try to scroll with it, it does not work..

[image: screenshot]

I am wondering if I have missed something so I am wondering if there is something else I have to do, or something along those lines.

```
#pragma - TableView Index Scrolling

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if(searching)
        return nil;

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tempArray addObject:@"A"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"B"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"C"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"D"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"E"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"F"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"G"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"H"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"I"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"J"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"K"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"L"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"M"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"N"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"O"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"P"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Q"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"R"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"S"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"T"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"U"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"V"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"W"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Y"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"X"];
    [tempArray addObject:@"Z"];

    return tempArray;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    if(searching)
        return -1;

    return index % 2;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The table view needs to be grouped alphabetically I believe - The temp array doesn't know how to translate the letter that you select into a specific index (it doesn't know what "a", "b", or "c" mean).

If you take a look at the ipod song list, you'll notice that each letter group has a letter section divider. You'll need to group your table objects into sections titled with letters in order to translate the letter "A" to an index. What apple's ipod list is actually doing is not scrolling to the first "A" entry, but the beginning of the "A" section.

Comment: okay, I thought that might have been the case, thanks for your reply.. looks like I will have to read around to figure this out. If you know of any examples online and have the link I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ah I see this is what they seem to be doing in this step I think.http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-sectioned-table-view.html

Answer (score 44):

You can use this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

Which tells the table which section corresponds to section title/index (e.g. "B",1))

This method is for returning a section corresponding to a Title. But you want to scroll your single section's row according to these titles.
So follow these steps:

1. Create global array means declare it in .h file

   ```
   NSMutableArray *alphabetsArray;
   NSMutableArray *dataArray; //--This contain your cell value i.e. Honda,Mazda--//
   ```
2. Define it in `viewDidLoad` method like below then return it from UITableView method..

   ```
   alphabetsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"A"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"B"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"C"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"D"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"E"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"F"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"G"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"H"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"I"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"J"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"K"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"L"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"M"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"N"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"O"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"P"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"Q"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"R"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"S"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"T"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"U"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"V"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"W"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"Y"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"X"];
   [alphabetsArray addObject:@"Z"];
   ```

   > [**Note:** You can also create **alphabetsArray** with dynamic
   >   contains according to your **dataArray**. For this follow **How we can
   >   create dynamic section index titles array** at below]
3. Now use the above mentioned method to get the title

   ```
   - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
       return alphabetsArray;
   }
   ```
4. Write your logic to scroll the UITableView

   ```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
       for (int i = 0; i< [dataArray count]; i++) {
           // Here you return the name i.e. Honda,Mazda 
           // and match the title for first letter of name
           // and move to that row corresponding to that indexpath as below
           NSString *letterString = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];
           if ([letterString isEqualToString:title]) {
               [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
               break;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }
   ```

****How we can create dynamic section index titles array****

1. Let us suppose that dataArray is like that

   ```
   [@"Honda",@"Maruti",@"Mazda",@"Toyota",.....]
   ```
2. Create a method for creating dynamic section index titles array as below

   ```
   - (void)createAlphabetArray;
   ```
3. Implements `createAlphabetArray` method as below

   ```
   #pragma mark - Create Alphabet Array
   - (void)createAlphabetArray {
       NSMutableArray *tempFirstLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++) {
           NSString *letterString = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] substringToIndex:1];
           if (![tempFirstLetterArray containsObject:letterString]) {
               [tempFirstLetterArray addObject:letterString];
           }
       }
       alphabetsArray = tempFirstLetterArray;
       [tempFirstLetterArray release];
   }
   ```
4. Now just call it anywhere when you want to change alphabetsArray contains

   ```
   [self createAlphabetArray];
   ```

Now you can create dynamic section index titles array dynamically according to your dataArray contents.

Comment: Awesome... you made every thing so clear that I don't need to look into any tutorial anymore... Thank you :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It works! But just wondering what integer do you guys return the method - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index ? I just returned a random number e.g. 100 and the right hand side index just works ( it scrolls) . So the index number returned from that method does not really matter?

Comment: @nick32m It does't matter because here we have only one section in which we scroll and use the alphabets array like a sections list.

Comment: @LalitKumar - Actually, it does matter in the sense that if you return a valid section index there then the `UITableView` will attempt to scroll _itself_, thus negating the attempt to manually scroll it.  It's necessary to return a value from this function that does not correspond to a valid section index (or to return nothing at all).  I suggest that `NSNotFound` is a reasonable return value to use in this case.

Comment: @aroth - you are right for returning a value (i.e. 0) from above method because it method demand. But you must define your own method for scrolling because you have only one section in which you want to scroll on basis of section index title.

Comment: @Lalit - thanks alot for great idea to use manual scrolling inside `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` method! Great approach in cases like mine when I has grouped rows already by another section's name!

Comment: return 0 didn't work for me, so I added return 1; which works perfectly fine now.

Comment: To clarify all the above, you need to return an index number that doesn't exist from ``sectionForSectionIndexTitle``.  If you return 0 (or some other section value that does exists), the view will scroll to that section rather than your selection.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar: Please change your code to reflect what davidjb is saying. If you return -1 it will work. If you return 0 it does not work. (it took me a while until I saw the above comment and fixed it!)

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return index;
}
```

It's hard to tell what's wrong without the rest of your controller, but I think that should work.

Comment: Is your tableview grouped or plain?

Comment: plain, thats a screen shot of it in my question.. do you think its because I have identical values?

Comment: It should be grouped so that the section methods are called.

Comment: thanks I am looking into this now :) thank you for your help, Once I have a solution I will update my post