# UITableView indexed implementation with single NSArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Hi every one I am trying to use UITableView indexed one. I have done all implementations related to that using Two arrays first one is for data with strings, second array is index of alphabets. I am able to see the index in the right side of table view but when I am clicking on it, Tableview scrolling to top. Here is my code for UITableview methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title  atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"index = %d, title = %@",index,title);


        NSUInteger row = 0;
        for(NSString *accountInfo in sortedDataArrayList)
        {
            NSLog(@"[accountInfo substringFromIndex:1] = %@",[accountInfo.accountName substringToIndex:1]);
            if([accountInfo length]>0 && [[accountInfo substringToIndex:1] caseInsensitiveCompare:title] == NSOrderedSame)
            {

                NSLog(@"row = %d",row);
                [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
                break;
            }
            row++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    if(currentFilterMode == FilterModeAll )
    {

        return self.indexArray;

    }
    return nil;

}
```

Any one please tell me where I am doing mistake. After clicking on the index button tableview scrolling to top only instead of as per the indexed position.

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I can understand is you concept misunderstood bit about the concept. For making output as you expected it needs sectioned tableview

You can read an excellent blogpost about this here
http://benedictcohen.co.uk/blog/archives/230
http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very clear while implementing itself, There is a possibility with single section too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408474/how-to-make-uitableview-scrollable-by-index

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are moving to row of section 0.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

I think you need to change to index section number instead of 0. Can you please try to set section that need to move.

Hope this fix your issue.. thanks..