# how to implement indexed tableview with numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am try to implement Indexed tableview with numbers but i unable implement because it have some issue in my code so please help me for implement that?

Here I have declare the number in string but i want to get in array so please say how to get these values in array?

This is the code i am tried...

```
NSString *numbers = @"100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000";
self.tableData = [numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
numbers = @"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20";
self.indexTitlesArray = [numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Comment: Which issue are you facing? Can you please put some error log or more description about issue you faced?

Comment: I Have no error in this code, i want to get the numbers in array but i cant.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
NSArray *self.indexTitlesArray = @[@"1", @"2",@"3", @"4",@"5", @"6",@"7", @"8",@"9", @"10",@"11", @"12",@"13", @"14",@"15", @"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20", nil];
```

the delegate method is

```
 - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return self.indexTitlesArray;
 }
```

for additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408474/make-uitableview-scrollable-by-index)

you need the same answer

```
 NSString *numbers = @"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20";
 NSArray *arr = [numbers componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
 self.indexTitlesArray = [arr mutableCopy]; 

  - (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
     return self.indexTitlesArray;
    }
```

output like in console

[image]

Comment: @Saravanakumar - I showed the 2 methods , it works 100 % sure

Comment: anbu you give the numbers in nsstring but i want in array how to get?

Comment: @Saravanakumar -- I am not get in what u ask

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have another doubt bro?

Comment: @Saravanakumar - yes bro, what I do for you

Comment: Suppose I click 5 in indexed value means in tableview 5th row want to selected, how to do that?

Comment: use didselectRow for select the index

Comment: bro i want to automatically selected while click assigned value of the particular row.

Comment: @Saravanakumar -- I attached the sample link also , check once on that link it is available in your need

Answer (score 0):

You have used *componentsSeparatedByString* to get each number separated from given string.

It always return array containing substrings. If you wish to get resultant array in another data type like NSInteger or int then you have to do it manually. You can run a loop for each elements in loop and perform type casting from NSString to int.

Type casting from NSString to int:

```
int dataValue = [@"100" intValue];
```

Below is **componentsSeparatedByString:** reference of **NSString**:

Returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator.

Declaration

```
- (NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString * _Nonnull)separator
```

Parameter separator: The separator string.

Return Value: An NSArray object containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by separator.

Discussion:

The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.

For example, this code fragment:

```
NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";

NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

produces an array `{ @"Karin", @"Carrie", @"David" }.`

If list begins with a comma and space - for example, `@", Norman, Stanley, Fletcher"` — the array has these contents: `{ @"", @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher" }`

If list has no separators - for example, `"Karin"` the array contains the string itself, in this case `{ @"Karin" }`.

You can find more detail [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)